# IF binding not working as expected when using ko.mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created two JSFiddle Examples for Mapping data with knockout.js.

(1) http://jsfiddle.net/9nn2qpp8/ without the ko.mapping plugin

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.entries = [
        { name: "one", type: "file" },
        { name: "two", type: "folder" },
        { name: "three", type: "file" }
    ];

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

(2) http://jsfiddle.net/q49vfy6q/ using ko.mapping

```
var data = {entries: [
    { name: "one", type: "file" },
    { name: "two", type: "folder" },
    { name: "three", type: "file" }
]};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Why is (2) not working in the same way as (1) regarding the evaluation of the if binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping plugin is automatically wrapping everything as observables - you need to treat them as such in the `if` binding:

```
<!-- ko if: type() !== "file" -->
```

rather than:

```
<!-- ko if: type !== "file" -->
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akx3v240/)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use the mapping, you convert each of the properties into an observable.

Every observable property is a function and so you need to execute the function to return the value inside.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/q49vfy6q/1/

`<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: entries()">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: type() === "file" -->`

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use `mapping` at all. You can pass `data` straight into `applyBindings()`:

```
var data = {entries: [
    { name: "one", type: "file" },
    { name: "two", type: "folder" },
    { name: "three", type: "file" }
]};

ko.applyBindings(data);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/q49vfy6q/2/).